# NATing multiple Wifi Interfaces with same IP under Ubuntu

Tags: networking, ubuntu, wireless-networking, ip, nat

Good morning everyone, little warning this might get quite a bit hacky and dirty.

I've got a rather strange Network configuration with a laptop (lubuntu) with multiple USB <-> WIFI dongles (Laptop wlan0 + wlan1) and an ethernet connection to an openwrt router that acts as an access point for multiple WIFI loadcells.

The openwrt router runs an DHCP server for the loadcells. Each camera acts as an access point and an DHCP server for the dongles and I cannot configure the DHCP inside them (cheap GoPro clone). veth0 is an virtual interface I want the different dongles to map to and have a transparent connection so I can address camera A with 192.168.3.10 and camera B with 192.168.3.11 from the laptops side.

So the problem is, that all the WIFI dongles have the same IP inside the same subnet.

[Figure of Network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i53jJ.png)

Question: How do I configure the chains for iptables and the routes to get this working if it is possible at all? There is no need for the cameras to communicate with the 192.168.1.x net only the laptop hast to reach them indiviually.

Regards, lor

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured something out that works although it is somewhat different from the original Problem:

```
ifconfig eth1 192.168.4.1/24 up
iptables -t mangle -A OUTPUT -d 192.168.4.13 -j MARK --set-mark 1
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -d 192.168.4.13 -j DNAT --to 192.168.4.4
ip rule add priority 1000 fwmark 0x01 table eth1_table
ip route add table eth1_table 192.168.4.4/32 dev eth1
iptables -t nat -A INPUT -i eth1 -s 192.168.4.4 -j SNAT --to 192.168.4.13

ifconfig eth2 192.168.4.1/24 up
iptables -t mangle -A OUTPUT -d 192.168.4.14 -j MARK --set-mark 2
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -d 192.168.4.14 -j DNAT --to 192.168.4.4
ip rule add priority 1001 fwmark 0x02 table eth2_table
ip route add table eth2_table 192.168.4.4/32 dev eth2
iptables -t nat -A INPUT -i eth2 -s 192.168.4.4 -j SNAT --to 192.168.4.14
```

I can now reach each camera on a different nic with the IPs 13 and 14 and they respond to the laptop with these IPs.